# Increasing/Decreasing count on click

Tags: javascript

Every new added LI items generates a reduce(-) and increase(+) button with a counter (default at 0), after putting onclick on reduce and increase button the counter only changes for first added LI item and not for others added.

Is the approach not right? or what am I missing in my code?

HTML:

```
<div id="countSection">
        <div class="text" id="countText">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span>Add</span>
        </div>
        <ul id="countUl"></ul>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var countText = document.getElementById("countText");
var entryAlert;
var entryDisplay;

countText.addEventListener("click", function () {
entryAlert = prompt("Whats the count about");
var counter = 0;
entryDisplay = `
<li class="enteries">
<span id="reduce"> - </span>
${entryAlert}
<span id="myCount"> ${counter} </span>
<span id="increase"> - </span>
</li>
`;

countUl.innerHTML += entryDisplay;

for (var i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {
    liList[i].onclick = function () {
        reduce.onclick = function () {
            myCount.innerHTML = --counter;
        }
        increase.onclick = function () {
            myCount.innerHTML = ++counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SamiHult this is the logic part of the code rest is all variables defined that's why didn't include it.

Comment: If you can't share more code, it's next to impossible to help. But I can tip that you will probably not want to set the `onclick` handlers for `reduce` and `increase` inside another `onclick` handler.